# SQL Server : same stored procedure works fine on 1 DB but slows on 2nd DB

Tags: performance, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have the same stored procedure in 2 databases. It works fine in the first one, but takes more than 10 seconds in the other database. I extracted it to query and have similar thing. Here is my query. Any help of experts would be appreciated.

```
SELECT     
    dbo.Installment.Id, dbo.Installment.InstallmentNo, 
    dbo.Installment.InstallmentOrder, dbo.Installment.Amount, 
    dbo.Installment.DueDate, dbo.Installment.AmountPaid, 
    dbo.Installment.PaidOn, dbo.Installment.PlotId, 
    dbo.Installment.SurchargePaid, dbo.Installment.surchargePaidOn, 
    dbo.Installment.PartialInstallmentId, dbo.Installment.Is_Lumpsum, 
    dbo.Plot.PlotNo, dbo.Plot.PhaseId, dbo.Plot.InstallmentPlanId, 
    dbo.InstallmentPlan.StartDate, dbo.InstallmentPlan.InstSurchargeDueMonth, 
    dbo.GetInstPlanDueDate(dbo.InstallmentPlan.StartDate, 
                           ISNULL(dbo.Installment.DueDate, GETDATE()), 
                           ISNULL(dbo.Installment.PaidOn, GETDATE()), 
                           dbo.InstallmentPlan.InstSurchargeDueMonth, 
                           dbo.Installment.InstallmentOrder, 
                           ISNULL(dbo.Installment.Is_Lumpsum, 0), 
                           InstallmentStartDate.DueDate, dbo.Installment.PlotId) AS Sutcharge_Start_From, 
    dbo.CalculateSurchargableDays(dbo.Installment.DueDate, 
                                  ISNULL(dbo.Installment.PaidOn, GETDATE()), 
                                  dbo.GetInstPlanDueDate(dbo.InstallmentPlan.StartDate, 
                                      ISNULL(dbo.Installment.DueDate, GETDATE()), 
                                      ISNULL(dbo.Installment.PaidOn, GETDATE()), 
                                      dbo.InstallmentPlan.InstSurchargeDueMonth, 
                                      dbo.Installment.InstallmentOrder, 
                                      ISNULL(dbo.Installment.Is_Lumpsum, 0), 
                                      InstallmentStartDate.DueDate, 
                                      dbo.Installment.PlotId), 
                        dbo.Installment.InstallmentOrder) AS days, 
                      case isnull(dbo.Installment.SurchargePaid,0) when 0 then
                  dbo.CalculateSurchargableDays(dbo.Installment.DueDate, ISNULL(dbo.Installment.PaidOn, GETDATE()), 
                  dbo.GetInstPlanDueDate(dbo.InstallmentPlan.StartDate, ISNULL(dbo.Installment.DueDate, GETDATE()), isnull(dbo.Installment.PaidOn,getdate()), dbo.InstallmentPlan.InstSurchargeDueMonth, dbo.Installment.InstallmentOrder, 
                  ISNULL(dbo.Installment.Is_Lumpsum, 0), InstallmentStartDate.DueDate, dbo.Installment.PlotId),dbo.Installment.InstallmentOrder) * (ISNULL(dbo.Installment.Amount, 0) * (dbo.InstallmentPlan.InstSurchargePercentage / 365 / 100))
                  else
                    isnull(dbo.Installment.Surcharge,0)
                  end
                  AS surcharge_calculated, case isnull(dbo.Installment.AmountPaid,0) when 0 then 0 else 0 end as Payment_Status,dbo.Installment.InstallmentOrder%6 as t


FROM           
    dbo.Installment 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Plot ON dbo.Installment.PlotId = dbo.Plot.Id 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.InstallmentPlan ON dbo.Plot.InstallmentPlanId = dbo.InstallmentPlan.Id 
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT PlotId, MIN(DueDate) AS DueDate
     FROM dbo.Installment
     GROUP BY InstallmentOrder, PlotId
     HAVING (InstallmentOrder = 0)) AS InstallmentStartDate ON InstallmentStartDate.plotid = dbo.installment.plotid
WHERE     
    ((dbo.Plot.InstallmentPlanId > 0))
```

STATISTICS IO for the one that works fine

```
(5089 row(s) affected)
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Installment'. Scan count 2, logical reads 109228, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Plot'. Scan count 1, logical reads 218, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'InstallmentPlan'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

and the slow one:

```
(64577 row(s) affected)
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Installment'. Scan count 2, logical reads 2842959, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Plot'. Scan count 1, logical reads 272, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'InstallmentPlan'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(1 row(s) affected)
```

My actual execution plans are here

[Fast query](http://brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Hy8XDLlML)

[Slow query](https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJcKvUxML)

Comment: The execution time difference can be explained by different data size, table indexes, difference in db configuration, difference in servers or more other

Comment: I am using SQL server 2012 - Microsoft SQL Server Management studio

Comment: Is the data in all the tables the same in both databases? Are the databases on the same instance?

Comment: data is different but tables, columns are same

Comment: that is probably the problem then. The optimizer will behave differently with different data sets. I assume there is more data in the tables of the longer running query?  You need to provide the (prerferably actual) execution plans for the query on both databases to be able to investigate further. You can paste them  @ https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: what is meant by execution plan?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/display-an-actual-execution-plan?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: see above. You will need to "Show execution plan XML"

Comment: I *really* recommend making good use of white space and line breaks. That code is *very* difficult to read as it is. Also [3+ part naming on Columns will be Deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/) and should be avoided. Stick to *good* aliasing and qualifying your columns with those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you have different data volumes between your two databases and while the query performs acceptably on the smaller database, it is slow on the larger one.

Looking at the two execution plans, we can see the optimizer is having to do full clustered index scans to perform the joins as there are no appropriate indexes. The main problem to me, seems to be a CI scan on the `Installment` table which is executed 2316 times, causing 5,583,876 rows to be read (against the larger database) The same operation reads 395,505 rows on the query with the smaller database. Your `STATISTICS IO` output tells us this is 2,733,731 reads difference. These are 8KB pages so therefore this a 2.6GB - fairly significant and likely the culprit of the variation in execution time.

You may be able to eliminate this scan by create a Non Clustered index on the `Installment` table:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_Installment_InstallmentOrder ON Installment
(
    InstallmentOrder
)
INCLUDES
(
    DueDate,
    PlotId
)
```

This should reduce the number of reads and speed the query up.

Even if this works, I suspect you may have more problems in future if your dataset continues to grow due to the two scalar functions in your `SELECT` statement - `GetInstPlanDueDate` and `CalculateSurchargableDays`.

Scalar functions are row by row processing which does not scale well to larger datasets, so you may need to remove them in future and replace with a set based approach (table valued function, JOIN, view, derived table etc)

Having said that, scalar function performance has been improved in SQL Server 2019 if the function is inlinable

Comment: the DB that works fine https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Hy8XDLlML and the lazy one https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJcKvUxML